# ShowWindow won't set focus or maximize

Tags: vb.net, shdocvw, showwindow

The following code will not set focus to the IE window that I need, nor will it maximize it like it's supposed to.

```
Option Explicit On
Public Class Form1
    Public Declare Auto Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
    Private Sub automateIE()
        Dim shellWindows = New SHDocVw.ShellWindowsClass()
        For Each ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer In shellWindows
            Dim isIE As Boolean = True
            Try
                Dim ie2 As mshtml.IHTMLDocument = ie.Document
            Catch ex As Exception
                isIE = False
            End Try
            If isIE Then
                If ie.LocationURL.Contains("url") Then
                    ShowWindow(ie.HWND, 3)
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your pinvoke declaration is wrong, it is VB6 version.  Visit pinvoke.net for the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Changed (VB6)

```
Public Declare Auto Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
```

To (VB.NET)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
...
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As ShowWindowCommands) As Boolean
End Function
Enum ShowWindowCommands As Integer
    SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
    ...
End Enum
```

Thanks to Hans Passant's comment